# Maps for an Android application: Any suggestions other than Google API?

Tags: android, google-maps

Map is the key feature in my Android application and I need to avoid Google maps API for the issues regarding the licensing. Is there any other options available which would be totally free?

Comment: Don't remember how licensing works but its a great alternative: https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/

Comment: You may want to take a look at OpenStreetMap https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid

Comment: @FilipeEsperandio how this map works, i mean MapBox has its own satellite system?

Comment: @tarikhelian Haven't look into details...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maps.me based on OpenStreetMap and have android api as opensource

https://github.com/mapsme/api-android